# Disabling bypass mode on Intel NICs

Tags: nic, pfsense, intel

I'm trying to install PFSense on some decommissioned firewall gear. I've installed PFSense just fine, except for the two NICs are stuck in bypass mode. I don't see any options in the BIOS to edit these settings. I am able to get into the webinterface of PF and see these NICs and turn them on. However, they're still in bypass and don't allow me to use them. Currently I'm able to get access to the machine over the management port. (SSH/WebGUI)

PFSense sees the NICs but it shows no uplink and the link lights are off.

The device seems to be based on a Portwell NAR-5530-320-450 platform; here are some pictures :

[image: photo]

[image: another photo]

Any idea how I could get this to work ?

The company that we bought these devices from are no longer in business and we were not able to send back these machines nor get support from them.

Comment: What make/model are these firewalls ? At the very least what are the NICs (run lspci from a shell) ?

Comment: It looks like these were built by portwell. Model: NAR-5530-320-450
The manual online does not match my devices see these pictures:

http://tinypic.com/r/2ur3vah/8
These NICs are Intel. I'll send you the exact info on the NICs shortly.

Comment: It looks like these were built by portwell. Model: NAR-5530-320-450


These NICs are Intel. I'll send you the exact info on the NICs shortly.

The manual online does not match my devices see these pictures:

http://tinypic.com/r/2ur3vah/8 
http://tinypic.com/r/qpm2o9/8


Couldn't edit anymore so I'll post it all again here.

Comment: What does ethtool show ? Does `ip link set up dev eth...` work ? Bypass mode is a property of the NIC making its ports behave as if they were directly connected when the server is off/not responding, for example to allow the appliance to fail without interrupting the network traffic. It'll most likely behave as normal once you bring the interface up.

Comment: @AndréB. I have just recently started studying linux. Should I boot to another linux distro? I don't see how to enter those commands from my PFsense bootable usb. Below are the interfaces that I got from the PFsense installer: (em2) is the management port.

em0  00:99:fb:21:c5:f3  (up) Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.4.2
em1  00:99:fb:21:c5:f4  (up) Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.4.2
em2  00:21:0c:21:c5:f5 (up) Intel(R) PRO/1000 Legacy Network Connection 1.0.6

Comment: From a quick Google it looks like bypass mode is managed by additional OEM hardware (this [forum post](http://www.zeroshell.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9849&sid=8130cb620951646314d10c1037ef513b#9849) shows some binary that apparently controls bypass mode), and this [post](https://communities.intel.com/message/104241#104241) on Intel forums further confirms that. I suggest you get in touch with Portwell and see if they can provide you a binary to control the bypass mode.

Comment: Thanks I will dig deeper into this. I am a sysadmin now, just now getting into linux. I'm working on my Linux Essentials cert now. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: To be clear, pfSense is **not** based on linux. Rather, it's based on FreeBSD, which on the surface looks similar, but is a completely different OS than GNU/Linux.